# Python: Creating a Map with a Movable Pin

Tags: python, image, pygame, python-imaging-library

I am creating a very basic fantasy game in Python. I have an image file that I want to be the world map, and I have an image file that is a pin to be used for the player's location on the map. So far I have used PIL to paste the pin over the map. Anytime the user wants his/her character to move, I can call a function that runs the following commands and updates the game's gui with the new map image:

```
world_map = Image.open('fantasy-world-1.jpg')
player_pin = Image.open('player_pin.jpg')
world_map.paste(player_pin, (x-coord, y-coord))
world_map.save('map_with_pin.png')
```

To me this doesn't seem like the best way to go about it.

The image of the pin is on a white background, and the white background is pasted as well, covering up parts of the map. Is there a way to make the background or a specific color transparent?

Or would there be an easier way to go about this with pygame or some other module?

Thanks!

Comment: Which library do you use to create your game? In pygame you would just blit the background and the pin separately every frame. Modifying an image on the hard disk to update your game graphics sounds really odd.

Comment: find PyGame tutorial and learn it. ie. [Program Arcade Games With Python And Pygame](http://programarcadegames.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a short demonstration of how you would move an object with a mouse click in pygame. First store the position of your object in a variable (called `pos` here). If the user clicks a mouse button, you take the mouse position (either `event.pos` or `pygame.mouse.get_pos()`) and assign it to the `pos` variable to update it. Then just draw the background and the pin image (`arrow_img` in this example) every frame and use the `pos` as the blit destination of the pin.

```
import pygame as pg

pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
BLUE = pg.Color('dodgerblue1')

background_img = pg.Surface(screen.get_size())
background_img.fill((30, 30, 30))
arrow_img = pg.Surface((54, 54), pg.SRCALPHA)
pg.draw.polygon(arrow_img, BLUE, [(0, 0), (27, 0), (0, 27)])
pg.draw.polygon(arrow_img, BLUE, [(10, 17), (17, 10), (52, 44), (44, 52)])

pos = (100, 100)  # Position of the arrow.

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Change the position of the arrow.
            pos = event.pos
            print(event.pos)

    # Blit the background to clear the screen.
    screen.blit(background_img, (0, 0))
    # Blit the arrow.
    screen.blit(arrow_img, pos)

    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

pg.quit()
```